# Intervalo de tempo em um while com javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola, tenho que fazer uma função em javascript, porém, preciso colocar um intervalo de tempo em um while dentro dessa função (executar o while da função 1 vez por segundo). Sendo que eu tenho fazer tudo isso aparecer em uma div no html

```
    function rotateText(id,dt)
    {
    var f = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var cont = 0;
    var fa, b, fb, c, y = [];
        // Esse while tem que ter o intervalo
        while(cont != 100){
        fa = f.length;
        fa = fa - 1;
        b  = f.charAt(fa);
        fb = f.slice(0,fa);
        c  = b.concat(fb);
        y = y +"<br>"+ c
        f = c;
       document.getElementById("Cosas").innerHTML = y;
        cont = cont + 1;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
rotateText(id, 1000);
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função setInterval.

```
function whileComIntervalo ()
{
    while (cont != 100)
    { /* Resto do código */ }
}

function rotateText(id,dt)
{ /* Declaração de variáveis */
    setInterval(whileComIntervalo, 1000);
}
```

setInterval recebe como parâmetro uma função e um valor de tempo em milissegundos (1000 ms = 1 segundo)

Comment: Valeu, funcionou!

Comment: Que bom que eu pude ajudar